# Как в select2 сделать disabled один option?

Tags: jquery

Хочется, что бы в плагине `Select2` (данные берутся из БД) после выбора элемента этот элемент либо становился недоступным, либо невыбираемым.
Добавляю атрибут `disabled`, получается вот так :

```
<option value="Адамович Фёдор" disabled="disabled">Адам Фёдоров</option>
```

Но его можно дальше выбирать.
Как сделать `remove` или `disabled` выбранной опции?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_disabled

Comment: У Вас он изначально недоступен. Я же просил сделать недоступным после выбора. И в Select2.

Comment: @Yulunga а вы какой версией пользуетесь? вот `3.4.0` неплохо себя ведет http://jsfiddle.net/5qdwf9ua/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать версию `3.4.0` и вообще версию 3
То там вполне справляется сам `select2`

```js
$(function() { 
 $(".select2").select2();
});

function multipleFormatResult(data, container) {  
 var markup = data.text;
 return markup;
}
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.0/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.0/select2.min.js"></script>

 <select multiple class="select2">
   <option></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/5qdwf9ua/1/**

Если говорить о самой новой версии `4.0.1`
То можно попробовать воспользоваться неким хаком:
Взять методы плагина, и в них проверять выбранное значение. Данное значение делать disable/undisable в зависимости от того, он был выбран или удалялся из селекта. А далее просто переинициализировать селект.

```js
$('select').select2();

var $select = $("select");


$select.on("select2:unselect", function (e) { 
  // console.log('unselected: ' + e.params.data.id);  
  $select.select2("destroy");  
  $select.find('option[value=' + (e.params.data.id) + ']').prop('disabled', false);    
  $select.select2(); 
});

$select.on("select2:select", function (e) { 
  // console.log('selected: ' + e.params.data.id);
  $select.select2("destroy");
  $select.find('option[value=' + (e.params.data.id) + ']').prop('disabled', true);  
  $select.select2(); 
});
```

```css
select {
 width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.js"></script>

<select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/zsc2Lqyt/**

К сожалению при удалении объекта будет появляться ошибка в консоли (ошибка самого плагина, которую если лечить, то самому). Но метод работает.

**P.S.** Честно говоря, способ будет работать даже если не писать `$select.select2("destroy");` ни в одном из методов. а просто рефрешить через `$select.select2();`. Вопрос при этом только один - не будет ли при этом расходоваться всё больше памяти.. Это можете сами проверить попереключав)

Comment: Спасибо. всё получилось. У меня 4.0.1.Я, правда, добавлял через jQuery : <code>$('.js-data-example-ajax option[value="' + name + '"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');</code>

Comment: @Yulunga Да это не важно. можно и через аттрибуты, можно через `prop`. Способов же много.... а  еще, хотел подметить, способ будет работать даже если не писать `$select.select2("destroy");` ни в одном из методов. а просто рефрешить через `$select.select2();`. Вопрос при этом только один - не будет ли при этом расходоваться всё больше памяти.. Это можете сами проверить попереключав))

Comment: Честно говоря, у меня `disabled` элемент остаётся в качестве выбранного, и можно его опять выбрать сразу же(если погулять по списку, то нет). пробовал и через `destroy` и без него, и просто `$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2();` и через `$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({placeholder: "Choose player", width: "300px" });`

Comment: @Yulunga не понял. нужно детаьлный пример на jsfiddle. потом что в примере что я привел все работает